Simple Transformers ClassificationModel freezes during training, making the terminal unresponsive
I am attempting to train a whole bunch of DistilBERT (Simple Transformers) Classification Models using 10-Fold validation. The process works as intended, but freezes during training (at different points every time) and makes the whole terminal unresponsive - only fixable by fully shutting down wsl and restarting it. There is no error/warning message.
I have a for loop, iterating over all training files in a directory (a separate model being trained on each one). For each file, the following function is called:
def calculate_qwk_for_file(original_data_dir:str, file:str):
    seed = 12345
    file_path = join(original_data_dir, file)
    dataset = read_data(file_path)

    print(file_path)
    num_labels = len(pd.unique(dataset['score']))
    kappas = []
    mccs = []
    accs = []
    kf = KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed, shuffle=True)

    for train_index, val_index in kf.split(dataset):
        train_df = dataset.iloc[train_index]
        val_df = dataset.iloc[val_index]

        # Optional model configuration
        model_args = ClassificationArgs(
            num_train_epochs=6, 
            overwrite_output_dir=True, 
            use_multiprocessing=False,
            use_multiprocessing_for_evaluation=False
        )

        model = ClassificationModel(
            'distilbert', 'distilbert-base-multilingual-cased',
             num_labels=num_labels,
             args=model_args
        )
        model.train_model(train_df)

        result, model_outputs, wrong_predictions = model.eval_model(
            val_df, 
            kappa=cohen_kappa_score, 
            acc=accuracy_score
        )
        print(result)
        kappas.append(result['kappa'])
        mccs.append(result['mcc'])
        accs.append(result['acc'])

    with open(f'results/qwk_results/results_{file}', mode = 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(f"kappa\t{np.mean(kappas)}\n")
        f.write(f"mcc\t{np.mean(mccs)}\n")
        f.write(f"acc\t{np.mean(accs)}\n")

I have also set the following os environment variable
os.environ["TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM"] = "false"

Package versions:
torch: 2.4.1
simpletransformers: 0.70.1
CUDA Version: 12.6
I reimplemented the whole approach using the transformers library and ran into the same problem.
